# What's the simplest Linux capable board I could make at home?

Tags: linux, pcb

I'd like to make a single board computer capable of booting Linux, with my low-tech garage tools (2 sided PCBs, reflow skillet, no plating through holes).

What's the simplest hardware design I could choose?

Are there any microcontrollers with enough onboard flash/RAM to run Linux/uCLinux?

Comment: Personally, I think it would be simpler to buy one rather than make one. A [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) is a pretty popular solution at $149.

Comment: I absolutely agree. But, I *want* to make one :-)

Comment: +1 for having the ambition for such an undertaking.  Best of luck.

Comment: I agree that it is certainly cheaper/easier to buy one than to build one. There are a variety of solutions out there... Here are a few that I'm aware of: - [Gumstix](http://www.gumstix.com/) - [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) - [Chumby](http://www.chumby.com/) (easily hack-able) - Plug Computers ([SheevaPlug](http://www.plugcomputer.org/), [GuruPlug](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-guruplugdetails.aspx), etc -- Check out http://www.plugapps.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd like to see this too, but my gut instinct is to say "maybe, but it's a *lot* of work".  Even the smallest Linux distro is going to need around a megabyte of RAM to run.  This means at least 30 or so additional pins for the RAM controller in the microcontroller, and a couple of big RAM chips.

One of the simplest architectures I know that has Linux for it is the Atmel AVR32 series of parts.  The smallest, the [AT32UC3A0128](http://atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card_mcu.asp?part_id=4126) comes in a relatively hacker-friendly 100-pin TQFP package.  This is at least amenable to hand-soldering, unlike most of the OS-capable embedded microcontrollers that come in BGA packages. (the chips that have the little solder balls underneath them)  You can get an idea as to the complexity of a circuit using that chip by examining the [EVK1100](http://atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card_mcu.asp?tool_id=4114) eval board.

Comment: That EVK1100 is a lot more complicated than is strictly necessary.  Those kinds of eval boards usually have a lot of extra peripherals - things like LCDs, buttons and such that are there to give you a leg up on getting output from the chip.  Making your own board you'll only include the things you care about and usually end up with a much simpler design.

Comment: Most eval boards, definitely.  The EVK1100 looks a bit better than many in by separating out those parts that are core and those that are peripherals.  At least it seems like that from the pics, I don't have one. :)

Answer (score 8):

[Linuxstamp](http://www.opencircuits.com/Linuxstamp) is probably your best bet.  It's open and has the PCB drawings, schematics, etc available.  But as far as doing it at home - probably not.  There's some very fine pitches on some of the parts.  You're welcome to try, but it seems like a fair bit of consternation to me.

Answer (score 6):

The Nintendo DS is capable of running uCLinux. You can get a used one for cheap, the only peripheral you need to run Linux on it is a microSD adapter (can be had for $15 from dealextreme.com) and a microSD (small ones are basically free these days)

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much need a decent size piece of RAM and flash outside the MCU/MPU.  If I was going to make a bare bones Linux system, I think I would go with simple cheap ARM with a serial port.  You could make a tiny PCB with 4MB of RAM, 2MB of FLASH, RS-232 transceiver, COM port, and the ARM.  You could get real fancy by adding ethernet, but that won't add too much real estate to the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like the following
http://hforsten.com/making-embedded-linux-computer.html

Comment: Nice project.  However while that can be assembled and soldered at home, it needs a professionally made PCB, while the question asks about making the PCB at home also.

Comment: hmmm yes. I guess thats going to be a little tough..